# marginal probability, three variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains

I got stuck with this:

P(A|C) = $\sum_{B}$ (A, B|C)

(B should be beneath the sum sign)

I understand marginal probability with two variables. But when it is three or more variables, I just could not make sense of it. What if A intersects C, but it does not intersect with the intersection of B and C? Why sum of B works? Can someone walk me through this? Thanks!

Comment: $B$ at the foot of the sum symbol is okay.  $\sum_B$ is the preferred typesetting for text mode.  Use `\sum\limits_B` if you'd rather have.  $\sum\limits_B$, but it really messes with line spacing; especially if you type enough to wrap onto the next line.  I dunno, is this enough text to demonstrate what happens?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot for the advice in typesetting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be aware of the definition of conditional probability.  $\mathsf P(A\mid C)=\mathsf P(A,C)/\mathsf P(C)$

For three events, same again: $\mathsf P(A, B\mid C)=\mathsf P(A,B,C)/\mathsf P(C)$

So just apply that and the Law of Total Probability.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\mid C) ~=~&\dfrac{\mathsf P(A,C)}{\mathsf P(C)} \\[1ex]=~& \dfrac{\sum_{B_k}\mathsf P(A,B_k,C)}{\mathsf P(C)} \\[1ex]=~& \sum_{B_k}\mathsf P(A, B_k\mid C)\end{align}$$

That is all.

---

As to why the sum works: If $(B_k)$ is **a sequence of *disjoint* events partitioning the sample space** -- well, in this case, at least exhaustively covering $C$ -- then: $$\mathsf P(A\cap C) ~=~ \mathsf P(\bigcup_{B_k} A\cap B_k\cap C)~=~\sum_{B_k}\mathsf P(A\cap B_k\cap C)$$

Comment: The sum is where I got lost. I still don't have the intuition. It does not say B is the a series of events partitioning the same sample space. What if B has no intersection with A or C?

Comment: Your text *should* identify that the sum is being iterated over disjoint events that exhaustively cover $C$, or similar words to that effect, because it does not hold otherwise. @www123

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!